# Difference operations in dictionary keys in python

Tags: python, dictionary, set, set-difference

I am running some Python3 code using the IDLE and I would like to understand why for

```
a = {'a':1,'b':2}
```

both:

```
a.keys()-'a'
```

(not even sure why this one works) and

```
a.keys()-{'a'}
```

produce the same result.

---

Weirdly enough, the second option seems produce different outputs once the operation is performed inside a function (and call from the IDLE) or directly run from the IDLE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to understand here is the kind of entities you are subtracting.

`a.keys()` is an iterable. Which simply means that it can be iterated through using a `for` or `iter`. Formally speaking , in python anything is an iterable that implements `__iter__` function. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884259/5596800)

```
>> type(a.keys)
>> dict_keys
```

And `dict_keys` is an iterable, how do you know that? because it has an attribute `__iter__`.

```
>> hasattr(a.keys() , '__iter__')
>> True
```

`a.keys()` returns a [`view`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) object. Which allows you to subtract other iterables from itself. As stated in the docs:

> ```
> dictview - other
> Return the difference between the dictview and the other object (all elements in dictview that aren’t in other) as a new set.
> ```

So, to subract something from `a.keys()` , that entity should be an iterable too.

In your case :

1. `a.keys() - 'a'` works because strings are iterables in python

   `>> hasattr('a' , '__iter__')`

   `>> True`

   So, strings are iterables
2. `a.keys() - {'a'}` works because `{'a'}` is a set, which is an iterable

   `>> hasattr({'a'} , '__iter__')`

   `>> True`

On the other hand if you try this:

```
>> a.keys() - 1
>> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

So, you cannot subtract two objects which are not iterables.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: It's incorrect to say that in general two iterables can be subtracted. `range` and `list` are iterables, but they can't be subtracted because they don't support the `__sub__` method. On the other hand, a set supports that method because it makes sense for that object.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are iterables of characters – `set('abc') == {'a', 'b', 'c'}`. The `-` operator for a dict’s keys accepts any iterable, so `'a'` is equivalent to `{'a'}` there.

If you used a longer string, it wouldn’t appear to work anymore.

Comment: It might be clearer if you mentioned that the documentation for `dict.keys` says that it returns a set-like object of the dictionary's keys. Then it's simple set operations, as you've demonstrated.

Comment: Is 'a' not a "char"? In fact: a.keys()-chr(97) produces the same output.

Comment: Diego when you call `dict.keys()` you are getting a `dict_keys` instance while the other is a `set` instance. The `__sub__` method is defined for one of them but not for the other.

Comment: @Adirio yes I know thanks. This is just to note that Reti43's comment "simple set operations" might not apply.

Comment: @DiegoFMedina: Python doesn’t have a character type. `chr` returns a single-character string. And you’re correct that `{'a', 'b'} - 'a'` producing an error is why I said “operator for a dict’s keys” and not “operator for a set” like Reti43 kind-of-suggested. =)

Comment: Fair enough. When I think minus in terms of sets, I think of `set.difference()`, which can handle iterables. I wasn't aware that `set.__sub__()` works only for other sets.

Comment: I would say the fact that `__sub__` on dict_keys doesn't behave like Set most definitely seems like an oversight and a bug. The fact that you can't do `set() - list()`, but can do `set().difference(list())` is on purpose and by design. It prevents accidentally passing the wrong type, exactly like the example above where the person passed a string (which is technically iterable). dict_keys should behave like set and allow arbitrary iterable.

It's especially bad since `dict().keys() - list()` returns a set, so you can't even do `dict().keys() - list() - list()`, that just seems broken to me.